# Difference of update_all in Rails 3 and 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3.2, I have the following:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.sort(shop_ids)
    shop_ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
      update_all(
        { position: index + 1 },
        id: id
      )
    end
  end
end
```

If I run `Shop.sort([3, 1, 2])`, it will output the following query:

```
UPDATE `shops` SET `position` = 1 WHERE `trip_days`.`id` = 3
UPDATE `shops` SET `position` = 2 WHERE `trip_days`.`id` = 1
UPDATE `shops` SET `position` = 3 WHERE `trip_days`.`id` = 2
```

However when I am upgrading to Rails 4, it returns the error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
```

in the `update_all` line.

I could fix this by using `.update`, but it will do TWO queries per updated row. One select and one update. I don't need two queries. `update_all` is more straight forward.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 4 you have to do it [like this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all):

```
where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1)
```